# SOLVED: Failed to write session data codeigniter on nginx

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I use codeigniter as my web framework. I am going to migrate from shared web hosting to VPS with LEMP.

**My script has run as well on shared web hosting.** But when I run on VPS (LEMP), I got this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Unknown: Failed to write session data (user). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/home/domain/sub.domain.net/application/cache)

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

This is my codeigniter session config file:
APPPATH = /home/domain/sub.domain.net/application

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'sid';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = false;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = false;
```

I use php5.6-fpm, my php.ini still on default configuration and I got that error (as I describe earlier).

But I tried to change session.save_path on php.ini like this:

```
session.save_path = "/home/domain/sub.domain.net/application/cache"
```

But no efect (I still got same error).

So, anyone can help me to fix this error?
Thanks.

Comment: check folder permission to save the session data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOVED:
Make sure nginx user has permission to read-write-execute on /home/domain/sub.domain.net/application/cache.